# Unable to install apk Error Code: -505

Tags: android, apk

I have research a lot on here and google but could not find the solution. I have uploaded an app on play store and it was working fine then i developed an other application by making changes in previous app project and  changed project id in build.gradle script and version code. Now if any of two application is installed in phone 2nd one always gives error code -505. Please help me, my both apps are live on playstore.

Comment: try clear cache and data of goole playstore and google play service.. if you are updating an app clear cahce of that app too..

Comment: thanx for you comment Adarsh I really appreciate your help.I am getting this error for two different apps. but i follow your advice and let you know the result.

Comment: adarsh-ashok i tried as you suggested but its not working.

Comment: ok.. glad you find the solution.. :) .. happy coding..

Comment: thanx Adarsh Ashok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my mistake and i am sharing it here as a answer if anyone else face this problem. I am using google maps in both applications and I use static package name in manifest for MAPS.RECIEVE permission and I complete forgot to change that package name. I was using following code

```
  <permission
        android:name="com.myapp.packagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Correct one is

```
<permission
        android:name="${applicationId}.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```